# How do I make a div fixed to the page?

Tags: css

How can I change the menu [here](http://marketbot.net) so that it's always there when the user scrolls down the page?

What code do I need to add/ remove/ replace and where?

Comment: You need to use `position: fixed` on the element you want to affix to the page, in your CSS stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I'm new to this, so can you help me with what EXACTLY to replace? I have no idea where to put position: fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **HTML** isn't good. You didn't close your `<section id="header" class="clearfix">` and many more. Run your page throught [HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it will tell you your errors.

As for your question, just add:

```
#header{
    position:fixed;
}
```

In your **CSS** file (*style.css*).

More about positions : [MDN positions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position).

Comment: Just to stress, adding that code won't work, until you fix the bad HTML.

Comment: that is true, he might get of the hook by simply wrapping the top into a div though.

Comment: The problem is that now my homepage can't scroll.

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer and @DannyBeckett in the comment, you first need to **fix your HTML**, and by that I mean closing the tags properly.

Comment: Now I'm getting these errors I have NO idea how to fix: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmarketbot.net%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Comment: Here is the Index.html code: http://pastebin.com/BBERw4si
Can someone fix the errors?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of a div which stays in the same position at all times on the screen.

To fix an element you can use the position fixed, and then position the element on the visible browser window by using the css top, bottom, right and left.

in this example it is fixed to top left, and has a height of 25px

```
<body>
    <div style="position:fixed; top:0; left:0; height:25px; width:100%;">
        Here you will get a bar which is fixed to the top left experiment to get your desired effect
    </div>
</body>
```

Simple solution for your case is to use

```
<section id="header" style="position:fixed;" class="clearfix">
```

and add a

```
</section>
```

before the

```
<!-- header ends --!>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the text seems to overlay the header, as you can see from marketbot.net. How do I fic this?

Comment: use the css z-index on the header and set it to 5